# Linear programming constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

How do I formulate a linear constraint using LP for the following?

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \geq 5$$ then $z$ takes a value of $1$, where $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, z \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Do you mean, *if* $x_1 + \cdots x_n \ge 5$ *then* $z$ should equal 1?

Answer (score 1):

For example $(n-4)z+4\geq\Sigma x_i$.